# Show a Total for a SQL Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add a Total line at the bottom of this sql syntax but thus far have received no break through. I have viewed the following but both of them do not adhere with my condition. Can someone please provide assistance with regards to this.

[Add a summary row with totals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934318/add-a-summary-row-with-totals)

[Adding a total row to the end of query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838347/adding-a-total-row-to-the-end-of-query-result)

```
select dm.Builder ||' ('|| dm.Lot_Size || '''s)' as"Builder",count(sd.Address) "The Count",
dm."Construction_ID"
from input dm
left join data sd on sd.inputfk = dm.inputpk
and sd.Closing Date >= DATE '01/01/2017' and sd.Closing Date < DATE '06/30/2017'
where dm.Construction_ID = 'AJR'
group by dm.Builder,dm.Lot_Size, dm.Project_ID
having count(sd.Address) > 0
order by dm.Builder
```

When I run it:

```
  Builder            The Count     Construction_ID 
Jake's Homes (55's)     2               AJR
Jake's Homes (65's)     3               AJR
Maggie's Homes (65's)   5               AJR
Maggie's Homes (66's)   2               AJR
Maggie's Homes (75's)   3               AJR
Maggie's Homes (90's)   1               AJR

 Total ---------->     16
```

Comment: `I am oblivious on why the result shows ones redundantly for the same Builders and Lot Size combinations even though I have grouped by ALL the columns in the script.` -- may be because of `sd.Address`   ?

Comment: Yeah that works needed to remove `sd.Address`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `group by` has `dm.Project_ID, sd.Address` which is probably causing it.

For total, you can use `ROLLUP`:

Try this:

```
select coalesce(dm.Builder || ' (' || dm.Lot_Size || '''s)', 'Total') as "Builder",
    count(sd.Address) "The Count",
    dm."Construction_ID"
from input dm
left join data sd on sd.inputfk = dm.inputpk
    and sd.Closing date >= date '01/01/2017'
    and sd.Closing date < date '06/30/2017'
where dm.Construction_ID = 'AJR'
group by rollup(dm.Builder || ' (' || dm.Lot_Size || '''s)')
having count(sd.Address) > 0
order by "Builder"
```

Comment: @Pythoner - You can just order by `"Builder"`. Updated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select dm.Builder ||' ('|| dm.Lot_Size || '''s)' as"Builder",count(sd.Address) "The Count",
dm."Construction_ID"
from input dm
left join data sd on sd.inputfk = dm.inputpk
and sd.Closing Date >= DATE '01/01/2017' and sd.Closing Date < DATE '06/30/2017'
where dm.Construction_ID = 'AJR'
group by rollup( (dm.Builder,dm.Lot_Size, dm.Project_ID) )
having count(sd.Address) > 0
order by dm.Builder
```

Just... why you need `count(sd.Address) > 0` ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the post is tagged with postgresql, assuming it is for that platform; as such, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS